# How to hide IntelliJ/Android studio Compose code/split/design bar?

Tags: android, android-studio, kotlin, intellij-idea, android-jetpack

The code/split/design bar takes a full code line of height, but I never use it.

In an Android project it is also visible for non Compose .kt files, which is completely unnecessary.

Is there a way to hide this bar in IntelliJ/Android studio?

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure you can - it's not visible for me on normal ``.kt`` files, only ones where there's a design view (e.g. layout XML, navigation graph XML). I haven't used Compose, so I don't know if that forces it for all ``.kt`` files, but it shouldn't - if you search for ``Design Tools`` in the settings, it treats Compose files as their own special case

Comment: Thanks, I have looked into `Android Design Tools` setting but there is no option to disable this bar. If the bar was enabled for Compose files only, it would be ok. But it bothers me that it's visible for non Compose .kt files also.

Comment: Try disabling all the custom plugins: https://i.imgur.com/cAYrxtJ.png If it does not help, create a bug request at https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/newIssue?project=IDEA

Comment: Thanks @KonstantinAnnikov, I tried disabling all the plugins. Then there was no bar. After that I enabled the Android plugin, and the issue came back. So its about the Android plugin only. I created the issue: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/IDEA-293672/Cannot-hide-Jetpack-Compose-code-split-design-bar

Comment: Have you figured out how to disable this Code Split Design panel?